# Facebook OAuth issue MVC4

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Annoyingly I have been trying to solve this issue for many hours, every answer is no direct solution:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I have been banging my head against the wall!.  I am using the facebook soap client for this http://pastebin.com/G7ysgbdX

This will allow us to integrate (with the user's permission) their timeline.  Facebook is saying the URL's do not match.  How do I test this?

This works locally but not on the server with the exact same code except http://free-rsvp.com/ instead of localhost:53111/

This is the below URL.  I cannot see anything wrong!

Any advice would be appreciated.

provider_%3dFacebookPro%26_*sid*_%3da80359b555c54b8f8d2f4f8e803f9125&client_secret=212360b3ea6478fd0a0491e736b54256&code=AQCyTDStiB5gsQpKMx4uI1yFesVnLnWfE3u70VsB02-4HSyUCTbcf_3oHMo7QQI2as_pw1tpFONs8tClq4FxCr4AzuCMzLBsRnyOM3dcattTATdU-ahq5cjr4lPJNp2gkTrpgWUmqDEVQ8PBvYFB1LdWJpojxRIC24lv0GkQSSqdrct41UGHfDjhnPfI1mV945NgVJSfebhJP7O0GWxP9o9g_4svDCKa2LtCRbo7nDfWLeiE9fGULhmuJDjefAFZ5VMiYj8SrA4QtZXIu8jUQSQT89VYEP8PuG2hS_wMr0TL_GmcvEhNzQ8psPpPWFYhmSo">https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=523007704381837&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2ffree-rsvp.com%3a80%2fAccount%2fExternalLoginCallback%3fReturnUrl%3d%252FDashboard%26_*provider*_%3dFacebookPro%26_*sid*_%3da80359b555c54b8f8d2f4f8e803f9125&client_secret=212360b3ea6478fd0a0491e736b54256&code=AQCyTDStiB5gsQpKMx4uI1yFesVnLnWfE3u70VsB02-4HSyUCTbcf_3oHMo7QQI2as_pw1tpFONs8tClq4FxCr4AzuCMzLBsRnyOM3dcattTATdU-ahq5cjr4lPJNp2gkTrpgWUmqDEVQ8PBvYFB1LdWJpojxRIC24lv0GkQSSqdrct41UGHfDjhnPfI1mV945NgVJSfebhJP7O0GWxP9o9g_4svDCKa2LtCRbo7nDfWLeiE9fGULhmuJDjefAFZ5VMiYj8SrA4QtZXIu8jUQSQT89VYEP8PuG2hS_wMr0TL_GmcvEhNzQ8psPpPWFYhmSo

**EDIT**
The url that takes me to facebook is:

provider_%253DFacebookPro%2526_*sid*_%253Dbfe82f104ab34d1aa0f44c477c4d7819%26scope%3Demail%252Cuser_likes%252Cfriends_likes%252Cuser_birthday%252Cpublish_checkins%252Cpublish_stream%26client_id%3D523007704381837%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffree-rsvp.com%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FDashboard%26_*provider*_%3DFacebookPro%26_*sid*_%3Dbfe82f104ab34d1aa0f44c477c4d7819%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page">https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=523007704381837&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ffree-rsvp.com%252FAccount%252FExternalLoginCallback%253FReturnUrl%253D%252FDashboard%2526_*provider*_%253DFacebookPro%2526_*sid*_%253Dbfe82f104ab34d1aa0f44c477c4d7819%26scope%3Demail%252Cuser_likes%252Cfriends_likes%252Cuser_birthday%252Cpublish_checkins%252Cpublish_stream%26client_id%3D523007704381837%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffree-rsvp.com%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FDashboard%26_*provider*_%3DFacebookPro%26_*sid*_%3Dbfe82f104ab34d1aa0f44c477c4d7819%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page

Comment: Is your call to exchange the code for an access token using `http%3a%2f%2ffree-rsvp.com%3a80%2fAccount%2fExternalLoginCallback%3fReturnUrl%3d%252FDashboard%26_provider_%3dFacebookPro%26_sid_%3da80359b555c54b8f8d2f4f8e803f9125` as the redirect_uri? the error message explicitly says you're not, so that's the first thing to check

Comment: Hi Where do I check that?

Comment: Hi @lgy please see the edit for the url to call. I believe they are the same

Comment: Your framework uses that URL to open Facebook's auth dialog which asks the user for permission then redirects to the `redirect_uri` provided, with a `code` URL parameter added- the next step of the  process is to take that `code` and pass it to Facebook in exchange for an access token. That exchange process requires a `redirect_uri` parameter and it must match the `redirect_uri` used in the auth dialog **EXACTLY** - the exception is stating that this is not the case - it may be tricky to debug if it's in an underlying framework, but it's most likely to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

here is a piece of my server-side authentication code (MVC4 project). The part you should look at is how redirect URL is generated - identically - in both "Authorize" and "AuthorizeCallback" functions - and passed to facebook client:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authorize(Guid eventId)
{
    var @event = this.eventRepository.Find(eventId);

    var redirectUri = ConfigurationProvider.HostingEndpoint + this.Url.Action("AuthorizeCallback", new { eventCode = @event.Code });

    var service = new FacebookClient();
    var loginUrl = service.GetLoginUrl(new {
        client_id = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppId,
        client_secret = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppSecret,
        redirect_uri = redirectUri,
        response_type = "code",
        scope = "manage_pages, publish_actions, user_photos, publish_stream" // Add other permissions as needed
    });

    return new RedirectResult(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri, permanent: false);
}

public ActionResult AuthorizeCallback(string code, string eventCode, UserProfile userProfile)
{
    var @event = this.eventRepository.Find(eventCode);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code) == true)
    {
        // means user clicked "cancel" when he was prompted to authorize the app
        // todo: show some error message? or just redirect back?
        return this.RedirectToAction("Event", "Dashboard", new { eventCode = @event.Code, feature = FeatureType.Update });
    }

    var redirectUri = ConfigurationProvider.HostingEndpoint + this.Url.Action("AuthorizeCallback", new { eventCode = @event.Code });

    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
    {
        client_id = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppId,
        client_secret = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppSecret,
        redirect_uri = redirectUri,
        code = code
    });

    var accessToken = result.access_token;

    // update the facebook client with the access token so 
    // we can make requests on behalf of the user
    fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

    // Get the user's information
    dynamic me = fb.Get("me");

    return this.RedirectToAction("Event", "Dashboard", new { eventCode = @event.Code, feature = FeatureType.Update });
}
```